How to catch a repeating pattern with regex in a string?
I have a bunch of strings like this:
abc#axyz(abc#axyz#a#aabc)abc#axyz. What I need to do is remove all the #a that appear in the text between brackets, while those outside should remain. I've tried the following:
\((.*?)(#a)(.*?)\)

But it only catches the first repetition. What am I getting wrong? Thanks for any input!

Try (regex101 link):
import re

s = "abc#axyz(abc#axyz#a#aabc)abc#axyz"

out = re.sub(r"#a(?=.*\))(?!.*\()", "", s)
print(out)

Prints:
abc#axyz(abcxyzabc)abc#axyz


You can use this method also :
import re

s = "abc#axyz(abc#axyz#a#aabc)abc#axyz"

out = re.sub(r'\(([^)]*)\)', lambda m: '(' + m.group(1).replace('#a', '') + ')', s)
print(out) 



I might just find the bracketed part and then do the replacements as separate step.
import re

s = "abc#axyz(abc#axyz#a#aabc)abc#axyz"

out = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', lambda m: m[0].replace('#a', ''), s)
print(out)

Attempt This Online!

r'\([^)]*\)' is probably better pattern. No worries about greediness or newlines... +1 from me tho.

@dawg Yeah, maybe. Depends on how different their strings are in general (the accepted answer for example also assumes there's just one pair of brackets). I like to keep things simple unless I have good reason not to. I'm undecided here.
